# puppet inline_template ignoring awk

Tags: ruby, regex, linux, puppet

I have following code in puppet and when i run it is ignoring `awk` filter **But** if i use `cut -d ' ' -f8` it works!

```
$hugepage=inline_template("<%= `grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'` %>")
notify {"Variable testing, hugepage size is ${hugepage}":}
```

Result following:

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Sysctl::Pgsql/Notify[Variable testing, hugepage size is Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Why it is printing `Hugepagesize:       2048 kB`? look like awk not working :(

On `irb` shell its working.

```
irb(main):002:0> `grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | awk '{print $2}'`
=> "2048\n"
```

## UPDATE

I tried following also but same result :(

```
$hugepage = generate("/bin/sh","-c", "/bin/grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | /bin/awk '{print $2}'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a quotation-mark-delimited string to either `inline_template()` or to `generate()`.  Puppet will interpolate variable references it finds within; in particular, it will interpolate the value of variable `$2`.  Supposing that that variable is undefined, an empty string will be interpolated.  The result is then identical to

```
$hugepage=inline_template("<%= `grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | awk '{print }'` %>")
```

which is precisely what you observe.  To avoid this, you can escape the `$`, or you can change the outermost quotes to apostrophes (requiring you to do something about the inner apostrophes).  I'd probably choose the former:

```
$hugepage=inline_template("<%= `grep Hugepagesize /proc/meminfo | awk '{print \$2}'` %>")
```

Comment: holy crap!!! i didn't notice that.. i thought `inline_template` work as same way it was working inside ../templete/foo.erb`  But you have cleared my doubt... Thanks man!!

Comment: It's not about `inline_template()` or `generate()` specifically; it's about the string argument you pass to those functions.  The interpolation is performed by Puppet, when it evaluates the string, before either of those functions is ever called.